# How to know which react tab we are on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-tabs

There are two tabs in my code and on click of the second tab I need to show one message but I'm not knowing how to know when the second tab is selected.

The problem is the selectedIndex is not getting changed at all and the message which I wanted to show is not coming up.

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(1);

<Tabs selectedIndex={selectedIndex} onSelect={(index) => setSelectedIndex(index)} />
<TabList>
<Tab>One</Tab>
<Tab>Second</Tab>
</TabList>
<TabsPanel>content</TabsPanel>
<TabsPanel>content</TabsPanel>
</Tabs>

if (selectedIndex == 2) {
   //Show something
   //Need this msg outside the tabs
}
```

I have tried this and as per the react-tabs documentation this should work but it is actually not working in my case. Please suggest any alternative for onSelect or atleast show how to change the selectedIndex while in the second tab.

Comment: tab index will start from `0`

so your initial state should be `0` and for condition `selectedIndex===1`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to use [**Controlled mode**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs#controlled-mode), which is activated by passing the `selectedIndex` prop.

Your issue is caused by setting the default state to `1` where as the first tab has index `0`. So change the `useState` to:

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
```

Then you can show the current tab as:

```
{'Current tab index: ' + (selectedIndex + 1)}
```

---

When using [**Uncontrolled mode**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs#uncontrolled-mode), you don't need an `onSelect`.

The Library will render the needed tab when using the following structure:

```
const Component = (
    <Tabs>
        <TabList>
            <Tab>One</Tab>
            <Tab>Second</Tab>
        </TabList>

        <TabPanel>
            <p>
                CONTENT - TAB - ONE
            </p>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
            <p>
                CONTENT - TAB - SECOND
            </p>
        </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
);
```

Comment: Hi using TabsPanel it will render the required thing but here I need to show that msg outside the tabs. That's the reason why I'm trying onSelect etc

Comment: I;ve improved my answer @Naidu.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But I didn't get where to change the selectedIndex on selecting the second tab. I tried it in onSelect but it doesn't work. Basically I need to set the state of selectedIndex on selecting the second tab but where will I do that if no need to use on Select

Comment: Im not sure what your asking. Maybe add your new code to your question to show what's not working?

Comment: const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

<Tabs selectedIndex={selectedIndex} onSelect={(index) => setSelectedIndex(index)} />
<TabList>
<Tab>One</Tab>
<Tab>Second</Tab>
</TabList>
<TabsPanel>content</TabsPanel>
<TabsPanel>content</TabsPanel>
</Tabs>

if (selectedIndex == 1) {
   //Show something
   //Need this msg outside the tabs
}

Comment: As you suggested I have used set selectedIndex to 0 instead of 1 initially. But that doesn't make any difference. Here my doubt is I need to somehow set the selectedIndex to 1 so that the below thing be shown when second tab is selcted.

I didnt get where to write this {'Current tab index: ' + (selectedIndex + 1)}. here I need to set the selectedIndex to 1 when I click on second tab. onClick, onSelect nothing worked. Could you suggest how can I set it to 1 and show the required thing on selecting the second tab.

Comment: I have added my latest code and my doubt as well. Could you please have a look